# how to get values from a fxml using java scene builder

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I am new in Javafx. I am using Java scene builder to create a form. When I saved it, it creates a fxml file. This is the code of my form..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-    Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"   xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
<children>
<Label layoutX="118.0" layoutY="95.0" prefWidth="82.0" text="Username" />
<TextField layoutX="200.0" layoutY="95.0" prefWidth="143.0" />
<TextField layoutX="200.0" layoutY="137.0" prefWidth="143.0" />
<Label layoutX="118.0" layoutY="143.0" prefWidth="61.0" text="Password" />
<Button layoutX="244.0" layoutY="190.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="submit" />
</children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image]
Now I want to get the values of those fields so I  can put that in database.. please any one help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you are actually using SceneBuilder, you can set the `fx:id` within it shown [here](http://puu.sh/4ASW5.png). Then select the Controller Class which will be instantiated if you build the FXML (mine is `de.thatsich.bachelor.javafx.DisplayPresenter` in this example)

In this controller you should have a `@FXML` field which has **exactly** the same name as the `fx:id` you provided in your `FXML`-File. These fields can be private if you like.

For example:

I have [this Button](http://puu.sh/4ATaq.png): the corresponding code for this button and its onClickAction would be

**DisplayPresenter.java**

```
@FXML private Button nodeButtonAddImage;
@FXML private void onAddImageAction() throws IOException {
...
}
```

and as you can see, you don't need to instantiate the Button yourself. The FXMLLoader will do this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add a fx:id="myWidget" in your FXML components like `<Button fx:id="myButton" .../>`

Then you add a java controller declared in your FXML and inject the component inside it with the annotation @FXML

```
@FXML
private Button myButton;
```

Once you get it in java, you can access any property, for your case it should be textInput.getText();